# WPF MVVM switch focus between 2 text boxes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application in MVVM with 2 text boxes and i want to set focus dynamicaly

In WPF i created 2 datatriggers for the textboxes "NodeBarcode_1"and "NodeBarcode_2"

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NodeBarcode_1_GetFocusNow}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value ="{Binding ElementName=NodeBarcode_1}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NodeBarcode_2_GetFocusNow}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value ="{Binding ElementName=NodeBarcode_2}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
```

In the viewmodel i created 2 boolean variables :

```
public const string NodeBarcode_1_GetFocusNowPropertyName = "NodeBarcode_1_GetFocusNow";
private bool _NodeBarcode_1_GetFocusNow = false;
public bool NodeBarcode_1_GetFocusNow
{
    get
    {
        return _NodeBarcode_1_GetFocusNow;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_NodeBarcode_1_GetFocusNow == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _NodeBarcode_1_GetFocusNow = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(NodeBarcode_1_GetFocusNowPropertyName);
    }
}

public const string NodeBarcode_2_GetFocusNowPropertyName = "NodeBarcode_2_GetFocusNow";
private bool _NodeBarcode_2_GetFocusNow = false;
public bool NodeBarcode_2_GetFocusNow
{
    get
    {
        return _NodeBarcode_2_GetFocusNow;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_NodeBarcode_2_GetFocusNow == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _NodeBarcode_2_GetFocusNow = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(NodeBarcode_2_GetFocusNowPropertyName);
    }
}
```

And i created 2 methodes that execuut when the user enters a barcode in the textbox

```
private void NodeBarcode_1_Execute(EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        IProduct NodeObj = ObjectFactory<IProduct>.Create("Node");
        NodeObj.Barcode = NodeBarcode_1_txt;
        NodeObj.Validation();
        labelAppObj.AddProduct(NodeObj);
        NodeBarcode_2_GetFocusNow = true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        NodeBarcode_1_txt = string.Empty;
    }


}
private void NodeBarcode_2_Execute(EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        IProduct NodeObj = ObjectFactory<IProduct>.Create("Node");
        NodeObj.Barcode = NodeBarcode_2_txt;
        NodeObj.Validation();
        labelAppObj.AddProduct(NodeObj);
        NodeBarcode_1_GetFocusNow = true;


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        NodeBarcode_2_txt = string.Empty;
    }

}
```

When the user scans the first barcode in textbox "NodeBarcode_1" the focus goes to "NodeBarcode_2". No Problem. But when the user scans the next barcode in "NodeBarcode_2" i want the focus to go back to "NodeBarcode_1". But that doesn't happen.

What can cause this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **reset** your States, in order to get the triggers work continously like this:

```
private void NodeBarcode_1_Execute(EventArgs e) {
    try {
        IProduct NodeObj = ObjectFactory<IProduct>.Create("Node");
        NodeObj.Barcode = NodeBarcode_1_txt;
        NodeObj.Validation();
        labelAppObj.AddProduct(NodeObj);
        NodeBarcode_1_GetFocusNow = false; // <--- Here
        NodeBarcode_2_GetFocusNow = true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        NodeBarcode_1_txt = string.Empty;
    }
}

private void NodeBarcode_2_Execute(EventArgs e) {
    try {
        IProduct NodeObj = ObjectFactory<IProduct>.Create("Node");
        NodeObj.Barcode = NodeBarcode_2_txt;
        NodeObj.Validation();
        labelAppObj.AddProduct(NodeObj);
        NodeBarcode_1_GetFocusNow = true;
        NodeBarcode_2_GetFocusNow = false; // <--- Here

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        NodeBarcode_2_txt = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I've made an minimal example. I didnt change the code really so this solution has to work with your issue unless you didnt name all the facts.

**Xaml**

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox x:Name="NodeBarcode_1" Background="Green">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NodeBarcode_1_GetFocusNow}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value ="{Binding ElementName=NodeBarcode_1}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NodeBarcode_2_GetFocusNow}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value ="{Binding ElementName=NodeBarcode_2}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="NodeBarcode_2" Background="Blue">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NodeBarcode_1_GetFocusNow}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value ="{Binding ElementName=NodeBarcode_1}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NodeBarcode_2_GetFocusNow}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value ="{Binding ElementName=NodeBarcode_2}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
            <Button Content="Simulate first" Click="Button1_OnClick"></Button>
            <Button Content="Simulate second" Click="Button2_OnClick"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
```

**Code**

```
private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            try {
                NodeBarcode_1_GetFocusNow = false; // <--- Here
                NodeBarcode_2_GetFocusNow = true;

            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
        private void Button2_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            try {
                NodeBarcode_1_GetFocusNow = true;
                NodeBarcode_2_GetFocusNow = false; // <--- Here

            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
```

The 2 buttons will now toggle correctly the focus. If this doesnt work, you might have something forgotton to tell.

Comment: I have tried this sulution but is doesn;t work. The focus goes from "Nodebarcode_1" to "NodeBarcode_2" but it doen't go back to 1